# Emitting signals in a loop from QThread

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, qthread

I'm working on a kind of video player, but I have a problem with implementing "Play" functionality, where frames are displayed at a certain time interval.

Skipping through frames using buttons or a slider works fine, but the following code doesn't. Moreover it seems to block the GUI thread and only displays the last frame.

```
void Player::play()
{
    for(int i = currentFrame_; i < replay_->getHeader().numberOfFrames; ++i)
    {
        setFrame(i);    // load and send frame i
        msleep(33);     // wait 33 ms
    }
}

void Player::setFrame(int frameNumber)
{
    currentFrame_ = frameNumber;
    replay_->setCurrentFrame(currentFrame_);    // load currentFrame into buffer
    updateFrame();                              // send it to the GUI to be shown
}

void Player::updateFrame()
{
    ReplayFrame colorFrame;

    colorFrame = replay_->getColorFrame();
    emit colorFrameEvent(static_cast<unsigned char *>(colorFrame.getData()));    // this is connected to MainWindow::showFrame(unsigned char *)
}
```

Note that the following code works fine:

```
// In main window, called upon loading a replay
QObject::connect(ui->sliderFrames, SIGNAL(valueChanged(int)), kp, SLOT(setFrame(int)));
```

So moving the slider actually does display the corresponding frame.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, of course that's happening...you are in a tight loop on the GUI thread that never yields control to the message pump until the loop is over!  :-)

It may be possible to synchronously call some kind of update function on your widget after `updateFrame()`, and you could watch the playback...but the GUI would still be frozen w.r.t. buttons you might want to push *(e.g. "pause")*.

Consider using a timer instead, so the GUI thread can run the message pump between frames:

http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qtimer.html

Comment: The `Player` object runs in a separate thread, so my understanding is that it would emit `colorFrameEvent` every 33 ms, while in between the GUI thread is free to do whatever it wants. Could you explain a bit more why it doesn't happen?

Comment: You edited your question since when I started to answer it.  :)  If the UI is locked, that means your GUI pump is not running.  Are you *certain* that `Player::play` is NOT running on the GUI thread?  Have you made sure your [thread affinity](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qobject.html#moveToThread) is correct?  Check by printing out the thread IDs you are working with to confirm things are running on the threads you expect they are.

Comment: Of course, you were right. Obviously only stuff that's inside `Player::run()` method runs in a separate thread. I somehow imagined that after calling `Player::start()` the object will just seat there in its thread and wait for the signals from the GUI thread... So I can now get it to work with yet another thread (timer-like), but how could I do it so that `Player::play()` slot executes in separate thread when `on_btnPlay_clicked()` is emitted from the GUI? Many thanks.

Comment: @Marian Read what I linked about moveToThread, but...my instincts say that trying to spawn an msleep-based frame updating thread isn't actually what you want.  Yet practical multimedia has always been a minefield for me, and this is why I like to live in the deeper levels of the stack. :-/ If you're finding yourself reinventing the video-player-wheel you might want to ask a more general question and get advice from folks who are more informed on the practice side of the theory/practice distinction with video than I.